# What is the difference between the two codes below

Tags: android, null, equals, boolean-logic

Here are two implementations of the same function. The first one written on my own and the second one I came across at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html.

```
**1st code:**
private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
    if (provider1.equals(provider2)) {
      return true;
    }
    else return false;
}

**2nd code:**
private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
    if (provider1 == null) {
      return provider2 == null;
    }
    return provider1.equals(provider2);
}
```

Comment: The 2nd code does a null check... If provider1 is null, 1st code will end up with NullPointerException...

Comment: @convexHull How 2nd code is related to 1st code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first piece of code may potentially throw NullPionterException if the parameter `provider1` is null. And we call `provider1.equals(provider2)` on a null Object.

The second piece of code checks if the parameter `provider1` is null or not, if it is indeed null then check if the parameter `provider2` is null as well.

If both provider1 and provider2 are null, they are considered to be same provider and this method returns true.

Answer (score 0):

The second code is safer for your app because it checks to make sure if `provider1 == null`.

Howevr, if provider1 and provider2 tend to be null in your application, I would rather write the code like this:

```
private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
    if (provider1 != null && provider2 != null) {
        return provider1.equals(provider2);
    }
    return false;
}
```